# Test is aborted while waiting for lighthouse user-flow.navigation

Tags: async-await, jestjs, lighthouse

I tried to create a test that should navigate between pages and collect lighthouse parameters. I created async test function (in jest) and added await before page.goto("my URL")- it worked. When I tried to do the same with user-flow.navigation (lighthouse library to collect performance metric) i received error
`FAIL  src/**tests**/test2.test.ts (6.643 s)
●  lighthouse tests › test onet.pl

```
request for '../../computed/image-records.js' is not yet fulfilled                                                                    
                                                                                                                                      
  19 |     page = await globalThis.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__.newPage();                                                                      
  20 |     flow = await startFlow(page, { name: "Test1" });                                                                           
> 21 |     await flow.navigate("https://www.onet.pl/", {                                                                              
     |     ^
  22 |       maxWaitForFcp: 60 * 1000,
  23 |       maxWaitForLoad: 70 * 1000,
  24 |     });

  at Runtime.linkAndEvaluateModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:708:5)
  at requireWrapper (node_modules/lighthouse/core/config/config-helpers.js:234:14)
  at node_modules/lighthouse/core/config/config-helpers.js:447:24
      at async Promise.all (index 144)
  at resolveAuditsToDefns (node_modules/lighthouse/core/config/config-helpers.js:456:22)
  at initializeConfig (node_modules/lighthouse/core/config/config.js:241:13)
  at navigationGather (node_modules/lighthouse/core/gather/navigation-runner.js:274:28)
  at UserFlow.navigate (node_modules/lighthouse/core/user-flow.js:131:26)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/test2.test.ts:21:5)
```

PASS  src/**tests**/test1.test.ts`

It looks like the **await** didn't work for this user-flow.navigation method  and lighthouse couldn't collect data for metrics

```
    at navigationGather (node_modules/lighthouse/core/gather/navigation-runner.js:274:28)
```

I increased the duration of the synchronous function but it did not help.
I added try-catch blok inisde async test- didn't help

```
try {
       await flow.navigate("https://www.onet.pl/", {
         maxWaitForFcp: 60 * 1000,
         maxWaitForLoad: 70 * 1000,
       }),
         expect(true).toBeTruthy();
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
```

My test2.test.ts

```
import { afterAll, beforeAll, describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { UserFlow, startFlow } from "lighthouse";
import { Page } from "puppeteer";

describe("lighthouse tests", () => {
  const customTimeout = 200_000;
  let page: Page;
  let flow: UserFlow;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    page = await globalThis.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__.newPage();
    flow = await startFlow(page, { name: "Test1" });
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
  }, customTimeout);

  test(
    "test1 ",
    async () => {
      await page.goto("https://www.onet.pl/");
      flow.navigate("https://www.onet.pl/", {
        maxWaitForFcp: 60 * 1000,
        maxWaitForLoad: 70 * 1000,
      }),
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      expect.assertions(1);
    },
    customTimeout,
  );
});
```

dependencies in package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "lighthouse": "^11.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^21.0.0",
    "puppeteer-screen-recorder": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "winston": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^47.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1"
  }
```